# Linking django object log to a project

Tags: python, django

I trying to add to my project django log object to my django project 
I followed these steps

1)pip install django-object-log

2)copied the object_log folder into your Django project.

3)Add "object_log" to INSTALLED_APPS

4)Run ./manage.py syncdb

5)add this url to my project urls ....url(r'yasmina', include('object_log.urls')),

But i don't know what to do next so any help plz ??

and this is one of the urls in url.py of the django object log ...url(r'^user/(?P\d+)/actions/?$', 'list_user_actions', name="user-object_log-actions"),

when i runned the server and added this url to my browser   http://localhost:8000/yasmina/user/2/actions/

I got error this url doesnt match

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Url pattern matches

http://localhost:8000/user/2/actions/.